# TLS error while cloning from git repository

Tags: git, ssl, github, clone

While trying to clone from GIT repository as part of the ONL (open network Linux) build process, I receive the following error. Does anyone have an insight over this? This is on Ubuntu 13.10 box.

```
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS warning alert has been received while
    accessing https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Clone of 'git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot' into submodule path 'buildroot' failed
```

Following is the output from gnutls utility. Looks like the hostname in the certificate does not match. Is there a way to skip this validation? I already tried setting sslverify to FALSE in the git config and it did not help.

```
root@ubuntu:~/git-openssl/git-1.8.3.2# gnutls-cli -p 443 git.buildroot.net
Resolving 'git.buildroot.net'...
Connecting to '140.211.167.224:443'...
*** Non fatal error: A TLS warning alert has been received.
*** Received alert [112]: The server name sent was not recognized
- Certificate type: X.509
 - Got a certificate list of 1 certificates.
 - Certificate[0] info:
  - subject `C=US,ST=OR,L=Corvallis,O=OSU Open Source Lab,CN=busybox.net,EMAIL=dnsadmin@osuosl.org', 
    issuer `C=US,ST=OR,O=OSU Open Source Lab,CN=OSU Open Source Lab CA,EMAIL=dnsadmin@osuosl.org',
    RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA1, activated `2013-01-25 01:31:38 UTC', expires
    `2015-01-25 01:31:38 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `e229f69e98cc9065e29cde829e79201dc0ad833c'
- The hostname in the certificate does NOT match 'git.buildroot.net'
```

Comment: The last part of the error message is the real error, "The hostname in the certificate does NOT match 'git.buildroot.net'".  The CN portion of the certificate should match the url you are accessing and in this case does not, git.buildroot.net != busybox.net. Try http or a different source.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - changing to http resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

The certificate is issued to busybox.net, which is the root cause of your error.

The simple solution is to just drop the https:// and use http://, as the URL is available at `http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/info/refs`

Comment: Thank you for the answer - changing to http resolved the issue

Comment: There might be a case where github access is behind a proxy, especially in corporate dev environments. You might want to check that your ~/.gitconfig exists and that it uses correct IP address/protocol(HTTP) to access github .